# What are the most commonly used words for use in identifiers?

Tags: coding-style, naming

Naming variables, methods, and classes is hard.  Having a good vocabulary to choose from can make things easier, and choosing commonly used words can make your programs more easily understood by other programmers.

For example:

- Naming classes after common patterns (Builder, Factory, Observer, Iterator)
- Built-in classes  (Executor)
- Action verbs  (get, set, build, connect, execute)

Are there any compiled lists of the most commonly used words in programs to aid in name construction?

Some lists I have found so far:

- http://source-code-wordle.de/

Comment: I prefer elaborate obscenities, usually regarding my co-workers' ancestry. I find it clarifies things, and a good cube-clearing brawl in the office has livened up many a dull day. The first rule of naming identifiers is you never talk about naming identifiers.

Comment: in the end I'd say that the site you linked shows exactly the words that appear in all the APIs out there.....

Answer (score 1):

For java: [link](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/reservedwords.htm)

For c++: [link](http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_keywords.html)

For c#: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

Googling "reserved words in [insert language here]" will get you the same thing for just about any language.

Comment: Sorry if my post wasn't clear;  I'm looking for a list of commonly used words in identifiers (e.g. get, set, copy, write, manager, provider), and not reserved words.

Comment: ahhh, my fault.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Should I delete or leave it considering that it is still related?